# Using JOIN statement with a WHERE

Tags: ms-access

This is probably a basic question, but I'm trying to build an SQL query for an access database that returns orders from a certain customer and I want to cross reference the customerID with the customer name from the customers table.

This is the query that I'm using

```
SELECT OrderTable.OrderNumber, OrderTable.CustomerID, OrderTable.OrderDate 
FROM [OrderTable] INNER JOIN [CustomerTable] 
    ON CustomerTable.CustomerID = OrderTable.CustomerID 
WHERE OrderTable.CustomerID = 1
```

I don't get an error and it returns the correct records (all orders w/ customer ID = 1), however it does not return the customer name...it just returns the customerID for each order (always 1 as expected).

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thank you!

Comment: I do not see the CustomerName being selected from the CustomerTable.  The join apparently works, but you need to add `CustomerTable.CustomerName` to the select statement to get that datum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifically asking for the OrderNumber, CustomerId and OrderDate columns.  If you want the customers name you have to include that in your field list.

```
SELECT OrderTable.OrderNumber, OrderTable.CustomerID, OrderTable.OrderDate,
     CustomerTable.Name
FROM [OrderTable] INNER JOIN [CustomerTable] 
    ON CustomerTable.CustomerID = OrderTable.CustomerID 
WHERE OrderTable.CustomerID = 1
```

A basic `SELECT` statement looks something like this:

```
SELECT FieldList
FROM TableOne
INNER JOIN TableTwo
    ON JoinCondition between TableOne and TableTwo
WHERE [Conditions that restrict returned rows]
```

You will only be returned those columns that you explicitly list in the `FieldList` unless you use a `*` (returns all rows) or `TableName.*` (returns all rows for TableName).

Note: It is recommended that you list out the fields you want back explicitly for a number of reasons including:

- Performance : Pulling one (or more) columns that you actually need requires less data transferred than pulling all of them.
- Code stability : If you add a column to the table you will get back columns in your query you may not want and could break your code.

Answer (score 1):

taking a guess here

select ... , [CustomerTable].[name]

```
SELECT OrderTable.OrderNumber, OrderTable.CustomerID, OrderTable.OrderDate 
     , [CustomerTable].[name]
  FROM [OrderTable] 
  JOIN [CustomerTable] 
         ON CustomerTable.CustomerID = OrderTable.CustomerID 
        AND                            OrderTable.CustomerID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query select,

from:
SELECT OrderTable.OrderNumber, OrderTable.CustomerID, ....

to: 
SELECT OrderTable.OrderNumber, CustomerTable.CustomerName, .... 
(or equivalent)